# Gimpel's PC Lint Value Tracking

Tags: lint, pc-lint

I'm a newbie to this site, so if I mess up any question-asking etiquette here I apologize in advance... Thanks!

This is extremely simplified example code, but I think it shows what I'm talking about: I have a C++ method that makes a call into another method to test a value...

`char m_array[MAX]; // class member, MAX is a #define`

```
foo(unsigned int n)
{
    if (validNumber(n)) //test n
    {
        // do stuff
        m_array[n-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

where: `validNumber(unsigned int val) { return ((val > 0) && (val <= MAX)); }`

The irritation I'm having is that PC Lint's Value Tracking seems to ignore the `validNumber()` call and gives a **warning 661 possible access of out-of-bounds pointer (1 beyond end of data) by operator '['**

However if I do it like this, Lint is happy:

```
if ((n > 0) && (n <= MAX)) //test n
...
```

So, does Lint's Value Tracking just not work if the test is a method call?

Thanks again,

HF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that `validNumber` is defined *after* `foo`, but in any case, PC Lint normally makes one pass over the code, and in such cases it doesn't see validNumber as a check for the boundaries for `n`.

You could try the option `-passes(2)` or even `3`, and see what Lint makes out of it. I think (but didn't try) that Lint would then correctly note that the value for `n` is within the correct bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! If we end up re-visiting this issue I'll try the -passes trick. For now though we just ended up #defining the valid check, which of course just puts it all in line and Lint likes it